# Finding covariance from a joint pdf that doesn't converge

Tags: probability

The question I am having trouble with asks to find the covariance of X and Y, so Cov(X,Y). A link to the pdf is shown below:

[image: joint pdf of X and Y]

I know that to solve this you do E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]. I started working this problem by attempting to find the marginal pdfs of X and Y, then trying to determine E[X] and E[Y] using those marginal pdfs. When doing the integrals for expected values though, I found that they do not converge to a value.

For the marginal pdf of X, I integrated from 0 to x with respect to y. I'm thinking that maybe my limits of integration may be off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done some mistakes calculating the marginal densities. For $f_X(x)$ you have to integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ for all possible values of $y$, namely:
\begin{align}
f_X(x) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{2}x^3 e^{-xy-x} dy = \frac{1}{2}x^2 e^{-x}\int^\infty_0 x e^{-xy}dy = \frac{1}{2}x^2e^{-x}
 \end{align}
By noting that the last integral was an integral of a density (which density?). You can calculate $f_Y(y)$ yourself. Now we do $E[XY]$:
\begin{align}
E[XY]&= \iint_{[0,\infty)^2} xy\frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-xy-x}dydx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{[0,\infty)}x^3e^{-x}\int_{[0,\infty)} xye^{-xy}dydx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{[0,\infty)} x^3e^{-x} \frac{1}{x}dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(3) = \frac{2!}{2} = 1
\end{align}
Can you try to do  $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ yourself? I hope this helped.

Comment: Why is it that you don't integrate from 0 to x for the marginal pdf? In all examples I have seen, to get the marginal pdf of x, you integrate from the lower limit to x with respect to y. Is this just because the support for both x and y here are 0 to inf?

Comment: @MicheleR I think that the density was nonzero for $y\in(0,x)$ or something like that in your previous examples. The idea is that you integrate over all possible values of $y$ to get the marginal density of $X$. You can see it intuitively as "calculating the probability" concerning $X$ without having to know what $Y$ is. Then you can better go through all value of $Y$. But that is how I intuitively see these kind of things.

Comment: @MicheleR This is because the possible values of $X$ do not depend on the values of $Y$. Both go from $0$ to $\infty$, and do not bound each other.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-ax}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{a^{n+1}}$$
for $n > -1$ and $a > 0$. (If you haven't seen this before, you can prove it by using the fact that the Gamma distribution PDF integrates to $1$ and by making substitutions.)

Now notice that
$$f_{Y}(y)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^{-x(y+1)}\text{ d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\Gamma(4)}{(y+1)^{4}}=\dfrac{12}{(y+1)^{4}}$$
as long as $y+1 > 0$ or $y > -1$ (which is true), and 
$$f_{X}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}x^3e^{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xy}\text{ d}y=\dfrac{1}{2x}x^{3}e^{-x}=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2e^{-x}$$
as long as $x > 0$.

Recognize that $X$ has a Gamma distribution with mean $3 \cdot 1 = 3$, and
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y]&=12\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y}{(y+1)^4}\text{ d}y\\
&=12\int_{0}^{\infty}y(y+1)^{-4}\text{ d}y\\
&=12\left[\left.y\cdot\dfrac{(y+1)^{-3}}{-3}\right|_{0}^{\infty}- \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(y+1)^{-3}}{-3}\text{ d}y\right]\\
&=4\int_{0}^{\infty}(y+1)^{-3}\text{ d}y\\
&=4\left[\dfrac{(y+1)^{-2}}{-2}\right]^{\infty}_{0}\\
&=2\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Lastly,
$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}yx^4e^{-x(y+1)}\text{ d}x\text{ d}y=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}y\cdot \dfrac{\Gamma(5)}{(y+1)^{5}}\text{ d}y$$
I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: When I integrate normally without using the gamma distribution function, I got that the marginal pdf of y is 3/(y+1)^4, and E[Y] = 1/2. Does this mean that you have to use the Gamma distribution function in order to get the correct answer?

Comment: I think that your marginal pdf for y is off because gamma(4) is 3*2 = 6....so that would make the marginal pdf of y have a 3 in the numerator.